# Prolog calculate sum of 2D list

Tags: prolog

I wrote this code:

```
sum_list([], 0).
sum_list([H|T], X) :-
   sum_list(T, Rest),
   X is H + Rest.
```

It calculates the sum of all list elements. For example if I call:

```
sum_list([1,2,3], X).
```

it returns 6. But I would like to also be able to calculate the sum of 2D list. For example if I pass `sum_list([[1,2],[3,4]], X)`. I would get 10.
But when I try to pass this list, I get:

```
uncaught exception: error(type_error(evaluable,'.'/2),(is)/2)
```

error. What is wrong with this error? I can't find any useful information about it on the net.

Comment: What were you expecting `[3,4] + 0` to yield?  And if so, why didn't you use it in your original code?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean. How then I can sum up 2D list then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum_list is expecting a 1D array, you can try something like this:

```
sum2D_list([X|T],R):-
sum2D_list(T,R2),
sum_list(X,R3),
R is R3+R2.
sum2D_list([],0).
```

I tried it with

```
sum2D_list([[1,2],[3,4]],X).
```

The result was

```
X = 10.
```

Comment: So If I want to make a function that sums up any depth list, I need to make a lot of functions that calls one level lower function? for example sum3D_list ... that calls sum2D and etc?

Comment: If you want something that can work with any depth you can use this instead
`sum(X,Y):-
    \+is_list(X),
    Y is X.

sum([H|T],R):-
    sum(H,R1),
    sum(T,R2),
    R is R1+R2.    

sum([],0).`

Comment: was that what you needed?

Comment: Yes, sorry it was a very late time for me. Thank you very much it works perfectly!